# Using Pre-Certified (FCC) Emitter - do I need unintentional transmission testing?

Tags: rf, fcc

I'm making a device - a keyboard - that uses a pre-certified RF module.  I host this device on my custom PCB, and have programmed it to receive the keystrokes (from switches on the host PCB) and transmit them to another, identical RF module on top of an Arduino - which interfaces with the computer.

With the exception of the module (and, I suppose, the Arduino which already ought to be certified as well), nothing else in my device exceeds 1.7Mhz, which - as I understand - is the cutoff for devices to be verified.  This comes from the exemption list, which states:

"Digital devices in which both the highest frequency generated and the highest frequency used are less than 1.705 MHz and which do not operate from the AC power lines or contain provisions for operation while connected to the AC power lines."

It's battery powered (the receiver is USB-powered).  Do I need unintentional transmission testing?  Do I need certification?  I'm just lost.

Comment: What makes you think the Arduino is FCC certified?

Comment: What is the question? If you need a FCC certification for your device? If so, i dont think you need it for short range devices. I cant remember what the distance limit is, but i remember that anything under a certain distance doesnt need certification.

Comment: You should get real advise on this, but my understanding is that if you have a transmitter with module level FCC approval and you are using the module in accordance with the module level approval (with an approved antenna, etc) and you do not have a second transmitter of any kind then you are ok.  You are still responsible for verifying conformance to all the FCC intentional and unintentional radiator rules.